# ListView and updating the Adapter when Activity is not visible results in poor performance

Tags: java, android, performance, android-listview

I have a performance problem.

So I'm writing a chat application and I have a `ViewPager` with Fragments in it for each separate chat, the `ViewPager` lives in `ChatActivity`, and the messages in the Fragments are displayed via a simple `ListView`.

Everything is smooth as long as I "minimize" my application. When the app is minimized, and I receive, say just 10 messages during that time, and return back to the activity, there is a noticeable delay (e.g. the standard Android Application restore animation does not play). If I minimize the app again, and restore it instantly, the delay is completely gone (assuming no new messages arrived).

There seems to be no correlation in the performance to the amount of new messages that have arrived: whether there are 10 or 500 new messages, the delay is the same.

I receive messages from a `Socket`, pass them to the `Chat` object, which simply passes them to the `ChatFragment`, which just uses `listView.post()` to post them into the `ListView`.

My `ChatFragment` and `ListView`'s adapter are pretty trivial so I don't post them here, the messages are stored in an `ArrayList` in the `Chat` object (the adapter just pulls them from there).. I'm really not doing anything "fancy".

To put it simply, when my `Activity` (and the Fragments in it) are paused, and new data is  posted to the `ListView`, the `ListView` (I assume) has to do "more work at once" when the `Fragment` is resumed and the `ListView` is "refreshed".

This might be a bit vague without code, but perhaps someone can tell me if my principle is at least right (i.e. simply post() the messages to the adapter, regardless if the `Activity` and `Fragment` are visible to the user?).

If anyone has any ideas what might cause this delay, I'd be very grateful.

Comment: What kind of multi threading are you using ? Do you use services ?

Comment: Yes, I use a service but not for the purpose of sending & receiving messages. I simply have a "Server"-class (an abstraction of IRC server) that holds a socket and its own thread, and dispatches events to listeners. So, I'm using just basic synchronization.

Comment: When the application goes to background and resume do you stop the service and restart it ? Or do stuff like that ?

Comment: Nope, the service keeps running for the lifetime of the application (it's actually a foreground service). But the service isn't really related to basic message dispatching, it's used for other purposes.

Comment: ok no easy issue :/ when the application go in background basically nothing is suposed to happen ? Service goes on, messasing goes on ?

Comment: Yep, all messaging is completely separate of the Activity/Fragment/Service lifecycles.

Answer (score 0):

My intuition about new messages and the `ListView` problem was completely wrong! What caused the slowdown was that I have a launcher activity that launches the previously visible activities or displays itself if there isn't one. Instead of calling `finish()` in the `onCreate()` of it, I simply called `return`! This caused the activity to go on with its lifecycle, doing whatever it does behind the scenes, causing the slowdown.